# Maven not replacing tags properly

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3, maven-plugin, maven-assembly-plugin

I have two wars say War-A and War - B. I need to build war - B re-using the src and resources directory of War - A with some minor config changes in web.xml of war-B. Hence I given the below code in war - B

```
<srcPath>${project.parent.basedir}/War-A/src/main/java</srcPath>
<resourcespath>${project.parent.basedir}/War-A/src/main</resourcespath>
```

But while building the war-B, Maven not referring the proper path of parent.basedir instead it is showing below logs

```
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\..\war-B\${project.parent.basedir}\war-A\src\main
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ 
war-B ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO]
```

However with the same configuration

```
<webapp>${project.parent.basedir}/War-A/src/main</webapp>
```

it is able to generate the war with webapp directory. Please suggest some solution and I am using eclipse + maven

Comment: Check https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/overlays.html

Comment: I checked the above link however its a multi module project and I dont want to create inter dependencies among project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

../War-A/src/main/java

Comment: Placing double dots instead of ${project.parent.basedir} worked for me. Thanks for the solution